# Thread title in post

Tags: forum, vbulletin

anyone knows how to add thread title variable (aka what hook to call) into Ad location templates>>ad_showthread_firstpost_start. I've tried calling it with {vb:raw threadinfo.title} but its not working. Vbulletin 4.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution very simple, It will be:
 `$thread['title'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try {vb:raw threadinfo.title} if you're looking to modify inside a template...